# How do I create a function/method out of this code and then call it to the main()?

Tags: python, methods, try-catch, program-entry-point, except

`enter code here`This is the original code that I wrote:

```
while True:
    user_input = (input(">>",))
    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    if user_input in range(1, len(something):
        break
```

I want to put in a method:

```
`get_user_answer(n: int, p: str) -> int` # This is what the method should look like kind of
   #But what should I write here?



def main()


#  and how would I call it?

main()
```

I'm learning about methods so I'm confused

I'm expecting it to work like the code I first wrote, but in a method instead that I call to the main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# get user answer function
def get_user_answer():
    while True:
        user_input = (input(">>",))
        try:
            user_input = int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        if user_input in range(1, len(something):
            break

# main function 
def main():
    # calling get_user_answer function here
    get_user_answer()

#calling main function here
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for trying to help, I managed to figure it out. If anyone is interested it was:

```
def get_user_answer(max_num: int, prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt)
        try:
            user_input = int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        if user_input in range(1, max_num):
            break
        print(f"Write a number between - {max_num}")
    return user_input
```

I probably didn't give enough information to help me in the best way, now that I think about it, but thanks anyway.

and calling the function to main:

```
user_input = get_user_answer(len(something), ">>")
```